# Calculate length of each object in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the length of many objects in R and return those objects with the name-prefix 'length_'. However, when I type this code:

```
A <- c('A', 'B', '3')
B <- c('A', '2')
files <- ls()
for (i in 1:length(files)) assign(paste("length_",files[i], sep = ""), length(unlist(files[i])))
```

This returns the vectors length_A and length_B, but each with the value 1 and not 3 and 2.

Thank you for any help,
Paul

p.s. I actually would like to apply this to a different function instead of length (GC.content from package ape to calculate GC content of DNA-sequences), but with that function I have the same problem as with the abovementioned example.

Comment: The length of each `files[i]` is 1.  The output of `ls()` is a `vector`, so I am not sure what `unlist` is doing there in the code

Comment: You could try `lengths(mget(ls()))` or more generally `lapply(mget(ls()), length)`

Comment: tldr; if you have objects you intend to loop over, put them together into one data structure (usually a list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A <- c('A', 'B', '3')
B <- c('A', '2')
files <- ls()
for (i in 1:length(files)) assign(paste("length_",files[i], sep = ""), length(get(files[i])))
```

This create a length_A of value 3 and length_B of value 2.

Comment: Thank you, the addition of the get-command resolves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In R 3.2.0, the `lengths` function was introduced which calculates the length of each item of a list. Using this function, as @docendo-discimus notes in the comments above, a super compact (and R-like) solution is

```
lengths(mget(ls()))
```

which returns a named vector

```
A B 
3 2
```

`mget` returns a list of objects in the environment and is sort of like "multiple`get`."

Answer (score 0):

```
A <- c('A', 'B', '3')
B <- c('A', '2')
files <- list(A,B)
sapply(files,length)
```

this will give you the answer but I don't know if it's what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is in the good direction. However, how will this code work if you have thousands of objects? And could it be possible to include to the sapply-function that the lengths are passed to new objects with the listname added to it? Thus not one object with '3' and '2', but an object called length_A with value 3 and an object length_B with value 2.

Comment: My answer was for your specific data.  There are other better answers particularly the one from @Imo.